# Best way of SELECT on large table with filter to filter out around 1m rows with indexes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, explain, pagination

I have a table `billing_billcycleorders` that contains a foreign key `billing_cycle_id`. There are around 0.9m records for a particular `billing_cycle_id`. I want to select the data in the chunks for ~5000 (or any best way possible).

The query result is exponentially increasing for values of `billing_cycle_id` with the higher number of records.

I have run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE, format text) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."id", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."created", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."updated", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."deleted", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."deleted_date", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."billing_cycle_id", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."order_id", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."pickrr_awb", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."amount", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."delivery_bill", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."rto_bill", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."pickup_bill", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."surcharge", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."cod_bill", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."qc_bill", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."qcf_bill", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."secure_shipment_charge", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."cod_amount", 
    "billing_billcycleorders"."meta_details" 
FROM 
    "billing_billcycleorders" 
WHERE 
    (
        "billing_billcycleorders"."billing_cycle_id" = 685081 AND "billing_billcycleorders"."id" > 0
    ) 
ORDER BY "billing_billcycleorders"."id" ASC 
LIMIT 1000
```

Explain Analyze: https://explain.depesz.com/s/k9rq7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paging through a table with `OFFSET` / `LIMIT` incurs the cost of walking through the combined number of rows and gets increasingly expensive.

Base your data pages on an index instead. You can start with `LIMIT 1000` like you have it, but instead of `OFFSET` in subsequent pages, use:

```
...
WHERE ...
AND   billing_billcycleorders.id > $greatest_id_of_last_batch  -- !
LIMIT 1000;
```

`$greatest_id_of_last_batch` being the greatest ID of the previous data page. That matches your sort order `ORDER BY "billing_billcycleorders"."id" ASC`. And `id` is a the PK, so it's unique.

Be sure to have a **multicolumn index** on `(billing_cycle_id, id)` to support this. See:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860)

And, of course, drop the `DISTINCT` at the top, that's doing nothing useful in this query (except making it expensive).

Aside: with a million rows per billing cycle, [list-partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) the table by `billing_cycle_id` might be a good option ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but here I'm not using offset pagination, I'm using the keyset pagination as suggested by you, and that's why my second filter comes in the query. But it requires an order by on "billing_billcycleorders.id" clause causing queries to be extremely slow. What is the other possible alternative?

Comment: @sirajalam049 This *is* the solution. Do you have the essential multicolumn index I mentioned? The query plan indicates you don't. Alternatively, once partitioned by `billing_cycle_id`, with a single `billing_cycle_id` per partition, you only need a plain index on `(id)`.